# Check NLog minlevel before logging?

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I want to enable developers to log objects as JSON with NLog. To do this I need to implement some logic before sending to nLog OR before sending to target.

I can build my own `Target(TargetWithLayout)` but I can´t find a way to check the log level from the config for this specific target/logger? Another drawback is that I need to make a new `TargetWithLayout` class for each target that we will use (EventLog, File, WebService and so on).

Another solution would be to do it in my `LogHandler` that uses NLog. The only way to know if I should translate the object is probably to read all the loggers from the config file, if any of them is set to log objects then I serialize. I am however not sure if I can check this information from the `LogHandler` (without doing it manually)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the NLog-Logger object to query active logging-rules:

```
if (myLogger.IsTraceEnabled)
   myLogger.Trace("Hello World");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the NLog json layout to write json in you log files, no need to check and do the serialization yourself:

```xml
<target name="jsonFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logFileNamePrefix}.json">
      <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
              <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
              <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}"/>
              <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
       </layout>
</target>
```

The log messages formatting is handled by NLog instead of doing it yourself.

[release notes nlog](http://nlog-project.org/2015/06/09/nlog-4-has-been-released.html)

Comment: That is nice if I only have one object that I need to send to the log. But in this case any class should be able to be logged as JSON to the log. So what I do is to serilize the object to JSON and then print it as a string. I do however not want to serilize the object if it is not to be logged according to the nlog configuration.

Answer (score 0):

To add some theory ;)

> Another drawback is that I need to make a new TargetWithLayout class for each target that we will use (EventLog, File, WebService and so on).

That's the reasons there are `Layouts` in NLog. Those are the layouts that could be used in the target, but those are independent of the target.

(don't get confused with Layout Renderers, those `${..}` things.)

There are multiple layouts (plain text, CSV, JSON)  (see [list](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Layouts)) , and you could easily add your own layout, analogous to adding a custom Target / Layout renderer, see [the wiki](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Extending%20NLog)